# How to use the .frame property in iOS?

Tags: ios, frame, pixel, cgrect

I am calling a custom picker in my application when i hit a button.

The picker looks like a bubble so i am pointing it to the button like this :

```
thePicker.presentFromRect = button.frame;
```

I need the picker to show 300 pixels down from this button. How can i do that?

How can i add 300 pixels height on the above statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use :

```
CGRect frame = self.window.frame;
frame.size.height += 30;
thePicker.presentFromRect = frame;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sir ,if you have time take a look on this one too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118655/stuck-with-uiactionsheetpicker-ios

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new frame and edit its height property like so:

```
CGRect frame = button.frame;
frame.size.height += 30;
thePicker.presentFromRect = frame;
```

Comment: Ok i found it. It should be frame.size.height . Correct your answer and i ll mark it as accepted :) Thank you very much

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice the dropped `size`.

Comment: If you have time take a look on this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118655/stuck-with-uiactionsheetpicker-ios

Answer (score 0):

First get the frame of the button so to be able to work on it.
Then change his height as you like, accessing the **size** attribute.
Finally, reassign the frame to the picker

```
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
buttonFrame.size.height += 300;
thePicker.presentFromRect = buttonFrame;
```

Comment: if you have time take a look on this one please:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118655/stuck-with-uiactionsheetpicker-ios